# Click event not triggered - Xamarin.Forms Android Toolbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a Xamarin Forms Application and I am encountering some problems with the android toolbar.
I have build a toolbar.axml where I set up the toolbar with 2 ImageButtons.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ProfileButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/AppNameView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingRight ="10dp"
        android:paddingTop ="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom ="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Title" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/magnifying_glass"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then, in the MainActivity I am searching the Button by Id like this :

```
var sButton = FindViewById<AppCompatImageButton>(Resource.Id.SearchButton);
sButton.Click += SButton_Click;
```

Now this SButton_Click is not triggered no matter how often I click the button... I can call sButton.PerformClick() which triggers it, but not by clicking on it... any Ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: I've met similar problem before. After updates of `Xamarin.Forms` `2.3.3.180`. The problem doesn't occur anymore. Could you please try update your `Xamarin.Forms` to `2.3.3.180`? If this doesn't resolve the problem, could you share a basic demo that can reproduced the problem?

Comment: Thanks, that did it :)